# Unable to render the JSP page using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

In my SpringBoot application I have 2 controllers. I am trying to render JSP page but unable to do so. I have `<app-root>` in JSP page which points to Angular application.

On hitting `http://localhost:8081//api/project1/mission/home` I get below error.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Jan 14 00:15:58 CST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

I have tried many solutions but none of them are working. I need help. Thank you

application.yaml

```
server:
  port: 8081
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/project1/mission
  tomcat:
    max-http-header-size: 72636B

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path:
      exposure:
        include: health
      path-mapping:
        health: healthcheck
  health:
    solr:
      enabled: false
    redis:
      enabled: false

spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
      suffix: .jsp
```

welcome.jsp

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <base href="/api/project1/mission/"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/dist/polyfills.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/dist/runtime.js" defer></script>
 
</head>
<body>

<div id="mission-app-ctnr">
    <app-root></app-root>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

FirstController

```
package com.google.mission.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class FirstController {

    private String message = "Hi";

    @GetMapping
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message", this.message);
        System.out.println(this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

AnotherController.js

```
package com.google.mission.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/home")
public class AnotherController {

    private String message = "Hi";

    @GetMapping
    public String serveTemplate(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a `/` too much on your URL. And where is your `home.jsp` file located? 
I do not think that you should use a `jsp` file when you're trying to connect to an Angular app. The way most of the developers connect a back-end with Angular is by using a REST API.

Comment: JSP file is under `src/main/webapp/WEB_INF/jsp/welcome.jsp`. Please help

Comment: packaging = `war`?

Comment: Its `jar` @xerx593

Comment: You say "JSP file is under ...." but it's supposed to be WEB-INF not WEB_INF.  Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the below dependency should solve the error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's puzzling...

Answer (score 2):

> #### [1.3.5. JSP Limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.embedded-container.jsp-limitations)
>
> When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some limitations in the JSP support.
>
> 1. With Jetty and Tomcat, it should work if you use war packaging. An executable war will work when launched with java -jar, and will also be deployable to any standard container. **JSPs are not supported when using an executable jar.**
> 2. Undertow does not support JSPs.
> 3. Creating a custom error.jsp page does not override the default view for error handling. Custom error pages should be used instead.

Putting item 2. in short: "It works *only* with `.war` archives"!

To change your jar to a war, follow these (few, simple) steps:

1. Change pom-packaging|gradle-plugin to "war". (https://start.spring.io packaging option)
2. Add a `ServletInitializer` to your application. (also best sample from: https://start.spring.io/#!packaging=war )

Comment: I was confused by question title: of course thymeleaf has [*nothing* - very few] to do with jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Your `context-path` is incorrect. You can set it to either `/` (for the root webapp, which is the default value) or a directory (e.g. `/myapp`), but not a subdirectory like you did (`/api/project1/mission`).

So I suggest that you remove the `context-path` setting from your application.yaml and map your controller to `/api/project1/mission/home`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/project1/mission/home")
public class AnotherController {

    private String message = "Hi";

    @GetMapping
    public String serveTemplate(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried, did not work. `JSP page is not loading` and getting error in console `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'`